# How would a quantum computer deal with small accumulated errors during a long computation?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

As I understand it, a Quantum Computer has qubits, where the system is in a state such as:

$$c_0 |S_0\rangle +\  c_1 | S_1\rangle \ + ... +\  c_n|S_n\rangle $$

where $c_0, c_1, ..., c_n$ are complex values that represent the entangled state that the qubits are really in.

Furthermore, we can manipulate these states in certain ways, such as by applying a unitary matrix, such as rotate around an axis.

However, these operations are performed by physical devices, and hence will not be perfect.  For example, a quantum gate may be designed to rotate by $\theta$, but in practice, might rotate by $\theta + \epsilon$, for some small but nonzero $\epsilon$.

Some proposed Quantum Computations take up millions of such individual operations; what would prevent the small errors from each of these millions of operations accumulating, and actually overwhelm the desired result?

Note that I am not talking about decorrelation; where some physical qubit gets a completely unexpected value.  Quantum Error Correction is supposed to handle that; however, QEC works by comparing various physical qubits; if they all drift off slightly, I don't see how QEC can correct for that.

Now, with conventional digital gates, they are designed so that each bit doesn't have to be exact; as long as it is close, the gate will act as designed (and produce an output which also might not be precisely correct, but close enough for the next gate).

Is there something similar for Quantum Computers?

Comment: Try to google quantum error correction

Comment: @Thomas: I don't see how QEC addresses this.  Suppose that, at a certain point on the computation, the correct qubit state should be $c|S\rangle + d|T\rangle$, but because of slight errors, the logical qubit state actually is $c|S\rangle + (d+\epsilon)|T\rangle$ (obviously, my example of a rotate can't do this; operations involving multiple qubits can); how can QEC detect the difference between what the qubit is supposed to be (according to the algorithm), and what it actually is?

Comment: Did you actually read about QEC? It is indeed not obvious that qbit errors can be corrected, because you cannot copy a qbit. This is why before the discovery of QEC codes (like Shor's code) it was not obvious that error correction can be done.

Comment: @Thomas: yes, I have read about QEC; it works (well, will work, once someone actually implements it) if you have a bunch of physical qubits, most of which are correct, and a few are wrong.  My question was: how does it handle it if all your physical qubits are slightly wrong?  If the $c_i$ values are actually quantized, that'd work (they then couldn't be slightly wrong); however I didn't think they were.  BTW: I'm not asking this in an attempt to prove that QC can't possibly work; I'm asking this because I'm pretty sure there is an answer, but I don't know what it is...

Comment: Again, I think you should take a look at how QECs work. The Shor code corrects arbitrary single qbit errors by encoding a logical qbit into 9 physical qbits. This just generalize to N logical qubits which get encoded as 9N physical qbits.

Comment: @Thomas: again, I really don't think you understand what I'm asking.  Yes, I know how QEC works; however, if the "correct" value of the logic qubit is $c|S\rangle + d|T\rangle$, but the actual value of physical qubit $i \in \{1, ..., 9\}$ is $(c + \epsilon_i)|S\rangle + (d + \delta_i)|T\rangle$ for some small values $\epsilon_i, \delta_i$, how will QEC recover the 'correct' (as defined by the algorithm) value?  I can see how it could reduce the average error by a factor of 3; that's not nearly enough for a long enough computation...

Comment: Google fault tolerant quantum codes

Comment: @poncho Quantum Error Corrections *collapses* analogue errors onto digital errors.  But you'll really have to read up on that! This site does not replace a textbook.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: I see; so the $c_i$ values are effectively quantized; not by the physics, but by the QEC logic (such like conventional digital logic).  I have further questions; however rather than bugging you for them; do you have a recommendation for a textbook?

Comment: @poncho I'd suggest either the lecture notes by Preskill, http://www.theory.caltech.edu/people/preskill/ph229/, or the book by Nielsen and Chuang, https://books.google.com/books/about/Quantum_Computation_and_Quantum_Informat.html?id=aai-P4V9GJ8C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quantum error correction codes involve repeatedly measuring an observable corresponding to an error syndrome. It's true that the *expected* value of the syndrome can vary continuously, and that this varying process corresponds to continuously varying amplitudes behind the scenes. But measuring the syndrome forces the system into either the "no error" state or the "one complete error" state (and the syndrome tells you how to fix it).

There are a lot more details, but that's the key idea. Measurement quantizes continuous errors. The next key idea is making sure you don't measure the encoded data as part of measuring the error syndrome, and that you get syndrome information for both bit-flip and phase-flip errors.

Comment: can you please comment on connections (if any) of this type of measurement with the Quantum Zeno effect?